# SAML DNS Resolution Issue

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-saml

We have an application using the Spring SAML Extension and we have set it up as an SP that works running on localhost against SSOCircle. We have now deployed in our customer's test environment and we are trying to get it to work with our customer's IDP.

We gave our metadata to the IDP, substituting `http://myapp-test.acme.com:8080/myapp/saml/SSO` for `http://localhost:8080/myapp/saml/SSO`.

After authentication, we see this in the logs:

o.s.s.s.m.MetadataGeneratorFilter -
Generated default entity base URL `http://someappserver.acme.com:8080/myapp` based on values in the first server request.

org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Intended destination 
`http://myapp-test.acme.com:8080/myapp/saml/SSO` doesn't match any of the endpoint URLs for profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser

In the browser window, we see that the request goes to `http://someappserver.acme.com:8080/myapp/saml/SSO`.

So `http://myapp-test.acme.com:8080/myapp/saml/SSO` resolves to

`http://someappserver.acme.com:8080/myapp/saml/SSO`

How can we change our code / configuration to handle this? I don't think we should hard-code the metadata to the app server.

Answer (score 3):

The URLs in the Service Provider metadata must correspond to real URLs where your Service Provider receives SAML messages from IDP. In this case the two differ.

You can update your `securityContext.xml` and change bean `metadataGeneratorFilter` by providing property `entityBaseURL`, with the correct URL, e.g.:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityBaseURL" value="http://myapp-test.acme.com:8080/myapp"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Without setting this property, Spring SAML defines the `entityBaseURL` and generates metadata with it based on the first request it receives. In case your application is available on multiple URLs this can of course be a different URL than the one your IDP actually sends messages to.

In case the internal URL as seen by the application server differs from the URL used by the caller (as in your case with the DNS resolution), you can force Spring SAML to think it's deployed behind a specific public URL by changing bean `contextProvider` to:

```
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
    <property name="scheme" value="http"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="myapp-test.acme.com"/>
    <property name="serverPort" value="8080"/>
    <property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="true"/>
    <property name="contextPath" value="/myapp"/>
</bean>
```

You can find more details in Spring SAML manual chapter [Reverse proxies and load balancers](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-load-balancing).